# Why does using [UIColor colorWithRed:gred:blue:alpha] lead to EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicolor

I have create a custom `UIView` subclass which should draw a simple dashed line. To define the color of the line I have added an inspectable property `lineColor`

```
// LineView.h
@interface LineView : UIView
@property (nonatomic,assign) IBInspectable UIColor *lineColor;
@end

// LineView.m
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])){
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])){
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setupView {
    self.lineColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:255.0 alpha:1.0];
    //self.lineColor = [UIColor blueColor];  <-- No Problem

    [self refreshLine];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self refreshLine];
}

- (void)refreshLine {    
    CGColorRef cgLineColor = self.lineColor.CGColor;  // <--CRASH
    ...
}
```

- If a color is assigned in the Interface Builder everything works fine
- If a default color like `[UIColor blueColor]` is assigned everything works fine
- If a custom color like `[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:255.0 alpha:1.0]` the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

> [UIDeviceRGBColor respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6000022d08c0

**Why is this?**

Comment: Did you try to change  assign with  strong ?  255.0 to  255.0 / 255.0

Comment: Thanks, this indeed solved the problem. But why is it OK to use assign with `[UIColor blueColor]` while it fails with `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `[UIColor blueColor]`, you don't create the object; you get a reference to it and something else manages its life cycle.

When you init a new `UIColor` object, you're responsible for making sure it is still valid when used.  "assign" doesn't increase the object's reference count; "strong" does.